Why does my HLA program that checks if values are increasing always output as false no matter what is inputted?
I don't understand why my code outputs The values don't increase even though I input increasing values for example
Enter a value: 2
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 10
The values don't increase
I also don't understand what this means
"after returning back to the caller, your function should not change the value of any register other than DX".
program IncreasingCheck;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );

static
    value1: int8;
    value2: int8;
    value3: int8;

procedure increasing( valuel : int8; value2 : int8; value3 : int8 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
begin increasing;
    // Checking if value2 is greater than value1
    mov( valuel, AL );
    mov( value2, BL );
    mov( value3, CL );

    cmp( AL, BL );
    jge NotIncreasing;

    // Checking if value3 is greater than value2
    cmp( BL, CL );
    jge NotIncreasing;

    // If both conditions are true, it's increasing
    mov( 1, DX );
    jmp Done;

NotIncreasing:
    mov( 0, DX );

Done:
    ret();
    
end increasing;

begin IncreasingCheck;
    stdout.put( "Enter a value: " );
    stdin.get( value1 );

    stdout.put( "Enter a value: " );
    stdin.get( value2 );

    stdout.put( "Enter a value: " );
    stdin.get( value3 );

    // Call the increasing procedure
    call increasing;

    // Output result
    cmp(DX, 1);
    je Increase;
    jmp NoInc;
    
    Increase:
        stdout.put( "The values increase!" );
        jmp EndProgram;

    NoInc:
        stdout.put( "The values don't increase" );

    EndProgram:

end IncreasingCheck;


The number from input is in value1 and you are checking valuel with a lower case L at the end. Alternatively you should call the procedure with some appropriate arguments.

The bit about DX is if you change something other than DX (for example AL, BL, or CL), you should put the original value back before returning. This is usually done by stowing the original value on the stack with push/pop.

I didn't read Randy Hydes book and play with his HLA but according to this
https://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/IntermediateProceduresa3.html#998787
it looks like You didn't pass arguments to increasing proc. Some random values are popped.
Also procedure should have prologue and epilogue to correctly pop values from the stack.
    push (ebp);         // procedure prologue
    mov (esp,ebp);
    
    
        ...
    
    mov(ebp,esp);       // procedure epilogue
    pop(ebp);
    ret();


This is corrected procedure:
procedure increasing( value1 : int8; value2 : int8; value3 : int8 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
begin increasing;

    push (ebp);
    mov (esp,ebp);
    
    // Checking if value2 is greater than value1
    mov( value1, AL );
    mov( value2, BL );
    mov( value3, CL );

    cmp( AL, BL );
    jge NotIncreasing;

    // Checking if value3 is greater than value2
    cmp( BL, CL );
    jge NotIncreasing;

    // If both conditions are true, it's increasing
    mov( 1, DX );
    jmp Done;

NotIncreasing:
    mov( 0, DX );

Done:
    mov(ebp,esp);
    pop(ebp);
    ret();
    
end increasing;


And how to trigger it:
increasing(value1,value2,value3);


